# how to convert data (to byte string?) for python pycrypto encrypt() function

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, pycrypto

I have an encryption function for which I want to use pycrypto encrypt() function. I'm new to Python (using 2.7) so I am having a hard time understading the input output data types. iv is generated with os.urandom(16), and I understand the output is random bytes. Is that the same as a byte string? the block_list is supposed to be 16 byte blocks of a message to encrypt (assuming no padding), where the msg is a plaintext string. When I encrypt, I want to xor a message block with a ciphertext block (I figured out how to do that with some added code) and then turn it back to a byte string. However, I don't think my function is outputting in the correct format. Any ideas? I'm not sure if I need to encode/decode.

```
def my_CBC_encrypt(key, iv, msg):
    my_cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

    c_temp = iv
    c_final = iv

    block_list = s[i:i+16] for i    in range(0, len(msg), 16)

    for item in block_list:
            c_temp = my_cipher.encrypt(c_temp ^ item)
            c_final = c_final + c_temp


    return c_final
```

Comment: Could you let us know what format you think your function is outputting? Why do you think the format is not correct? What output and/or errors are you getting?